# UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary status bar solid/white

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

I'm creating an app, that is in some point turning photo library on. The problem is that status bar is black transparent in photo library while i want a default application one (solid white). Is there any way to change it..?

I would add, that i tried regarding to this: [iOS SDK - How to get the status bar back when using UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542350/ios-sdk-how-to-get-the-status-bar-back-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller) method:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
}
```

works only for camera for me, not photo library. Of course i tried with default style too.

UPDATE: i found out a way to change navigation bar:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
   willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                 animated:(BOOL)animated {
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
}
```

This one works, however status bar style is still dark, while i need the default application one, so white.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem in a different way. To keep the status bar always the same i just added viewDidAppear method, that is written in my main post to my rootViewController, so it is same all the time including turning photo library on