# show statusbar in camera imagePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am woking on imagePicker where i need to show camera with some overlay view.But it's hiding status bar please tell me how i can show it here is a code

```
imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;

imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;

imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, 0.5f, 0.5f);


imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.tabBarController.view;

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

imagePickerController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542350/ios-sdk-how-to-get-the-status-bar-back-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: @peko but still not a working solution available

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
```

Comment: sorry forget to include the second line

Comment: try the following in the:  viewDidAppear [self performSelector:@selector(showStatusBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1]; and put [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone] in showStatusBar ... that's all i got.. works for me this.