# UIImagePickerController in iOS 7 status bar

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios7, uistatusbar

In io7,the status bar on top a view is a nightmare.Fortunally i managed to make it work so it will be placed above the view.I did it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
         self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(152/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(51/255.0) alpha:1] ;
        CGRect frame = self.topNav.frame; frame.origin.y = 20;
        self.topNav.frame = frame;
    }
....
}
```

Now my status bar is above my navigation bar.

But when it comes to calling `UIImagePickerController` things are different.The above code has no effect.
I tried to do this:

```
- (void)showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{


    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {

            CGRect frame = self.imagePickerController.frame; frame.origin.y = 20;
           self.imagePickerController.frame = frame;
        }

    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing=YES;
....
}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Any chance that my status bar(when displaying the camera for taking pictures) above the camera controls?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this, [imagePickerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, itsCurrentHeight - 20)];

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have same problem... and solve my proble...
Add The key in .plist file

```
'View controller-based status bar appearance' and set to NO.
```

And add in appDelegate.

```
[application setStatusBarHidden:NO]; 
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
```

Note:- change the  `**setStatusBarStyle**` according to your app background color

Comment: The new status bar is giving me headaches.I had to          self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(152/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(51/255.0) alpha:1] ;
for every view so it will color the status bar.

Comment: I tried as said above but its not working. is there any other things to be modified along with this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18953517/1271057 this answer helped me to hide the status that overlaps the camera roll

Comment: you want to hide the status bar

Comment: Vamsi575g, what is the problem? i can post code but first tell me what 's the problem.I didn't had to hide the status bar,just draw the pickerController 20 points lower.    [imagePickerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, self.imagePickerController.view.frame.size.height - 20)];

Comment: `'View controller-based status bar appearance'` must have a capital V.

Answer (score 0):

Set View controller-based status bar appearance' and set to NO.

And add in appDelegate.

[application setStatusBarHidden:NO]; 
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In App's Info.plist file add:

```
"View controller-based status bar appearance" == NO
```

In appdelegae.m file,add following code in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
  [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is a bug in iOS 7.0 and it's fixed in iOS 7.1**

Comment: I still see this in 7.1