# Camera photo mode fullscreen on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, fullscreen, ios-camera

Is there a way to set the camera photo mode **fullscreen** on an iPod 5gen with iOS7.1? When you are going to take a photo, the photo mode is not in fullscreen, only the video mode is in fullscreen, so, is there a way to change it? (I think the same problem must happen on an iPhone 5 and greater).

Here is my code so far, it displays the control but partially, not fullscreen, and the control gets aligned to the top because the camera controls are removed from the view:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.allowsEditing = NO;
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

//self.picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes; //just for the record
self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

self.picker.cameraOverlayView = [self buildOverlay]; //some custom views

[self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply proper  CGAffineTransform transformation in order to set camera mode.

Try out the following link this may help you:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779628/how-to-get-the-custom-overlay-for-uiimagepicker-camera-to-be-full-screen-in-ios)