# Camera Overlay View on Just Capture Section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

I am trying to add a `cameraOverlayView` on a `UIImagePickerController`, but I want the overlay to cover just the part of the screen that shows what will be captured by the camera, not the "Cancel" button, take photo button, flash settings, or anything like that. How can I dynamically determine what the frame of the `UIImageView` of my overlay should be?

I've attached an image to illustrate exactly the section I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779628/how-to-get-the-custom-overlay-for-uiimagepicker-camera-to-be-full-screen-in-ios

Comment: @iPatel That is not at all what I'm asking.

Answer (score 6):

you can use AVCamCaptureManager to get overlay  which cover just the part of the screen that shows what will be captured by the camera only , not buttons

Comment: Could you be more specific? `AVCamCaptureManager` is not a class in any iOS framework.

Comment: Yes sure, It is a 3rd party library tool. this link will help you more https://github.com/OpenWatch/AVCam

Comment: Is there a modern way to achieve this same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

i had same situation, what i did, i created an UIImageView like follow:

```
    myview                 = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    myview.frame            =  CGRectMake(0, 68, 320, 430);
// note that these frames were as per my needs, you can manipulate them as per yours.
```

then add this image view as

```
myImagePicker.cameraOverlayView   = myview;
```

try this with setting some background color and check whether its covering entire camera part or not, you would just need to set frames, thats all!!!

And yes it does work!

Comment: Yes, I realize that setting the `frame` is the solution. What I'm wondering is how to **dynamically** calculate the `frame`, as opposed to just figuring out magic numbers.

Comment: I have managed to add an overlayview but the problem is , when I am taking the picture i just want to take the part inside the overlayView. Did you managed to do that ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56187599/8732045