# iOS 7 UIImagePickerController navigationbar overlap

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I ran into a problem accessing photo library in iOS7 (iOS6 is OK). It seems navigation bar overlaps the photo album view, I tried to set `picker.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` but it doesn't work.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    picker.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Look at my screenshot

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046070/uiimagepickercontroller-in-ios-7-status-bar check it may be give some idea

Comment: still not work, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

UIImagePickerController set translucent = NO to navigation Bar

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

After this, implement this code in your UIImagePickerController delegate:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]])
    {        
        viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
        viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found I didn't need the first part, only that delegate method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of the above answer:

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if navigationController.isKindOfClass(UIImagePickerController.self) {
            viewController.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
            viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
        }
    }
```

Comment: this gives me crash on ipad ??

Answer (score 0):

As user2192708 mentioned, I think the main issue here is changing the default translucent property of the picker navigationBar and I'm not sure you need to change anything else:

```
picker.navigationBar.translucent = NO
```

This will cause the the navigation bar to use the UINavigationBar appearance if you set this somewhere in your app or the "default" if not.