# Adding a subview to a view controller messes up with a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uikit

I have a `UIViewController` that has a `UITableView` as a subview. I want to add a background view under the table view but when I add it, the controller's `edgesForExtendedLayout` seem to be messed up

This is correct:
[image]

This is not correct:
[image]

My `viewDidLoad` method looks like this. If I do not add the subview, all looks ok.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // UITableView
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:TAManeuvreCellId];

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];


    UIView *backgroundBlurView = [[UIView alloc] init];


    // autolayout
    backgroundBlurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(backgroundBlurView, _tableView);

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // comment this and everything is ok
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundBlurView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundBlurView];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[backgroundBlurView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[backgroundBlurView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}
```

Comment: Could you try `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = FALSE;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the fix for this is setting:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = FALSE;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

See:

[How to prevent UINavigationBar from covering top of view in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953509/how-to-prevent-uinavigationbar-from-covering-top-of-view-in-ios-7)

[iOS 7 UIImagePickerController navigationbar overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783321/ios-7-uiimagepickercontroller-navigationbar-overlap)

Comment: The thing is that I want my navigation bar to be translucent with extended layout to achieve a blur effect on my content.

Comment: If you want that than you would need to offset the frame.orgin.y and decrease the height of the tableview by that offset.

Comment: You may also have an option to use autolayout to set the top edge of the tableview to the top layout guideline of the controller.

Comment: So when the nav bar in translucent, the table view has to end under the topLayoutGuide instead of taking the entire controller's view ?

Comment: If the table view ends just under the `topLayoutGuide` then the nav bar blur is not applied on the table cells