# iOS 7 StatusBar issue when I am using UIImagePickerController Allow editing

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, uistatusbar

I study related iOS 7 status-Bar Maintain, but am I facing an issue while I am using `UIImagePickerController`. Allow editing that Editing Window shows 20 pixels space at the top bar.

I used the code and first I set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in `info.plist` and set the delegate method:

#### Appdelegate.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIWindow *background;
```

#### Appdelegate.m

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {

    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);

    self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);

    background = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, 20)];
    background.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
    [background setHidden:NO];
}
```

In my home view controller that has no effect, so I put in my home viewController, one method for changing the background color of statusbar:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width,screenHeight-20);
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"userIsMale"]) {
        [tempWindow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(46.0/255.0) green:(134.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1]];
    }
    else {
        [tempWindow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(246.0/255.0) green:(26.0/255.0) blue:(113.0/255.0) alpha:1]];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Now when I present `UIImagePickerController` allow editing window that shows it like this:

[image]

I tried with this solution for hide statusbar while present `UIImagePickerController`:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

And show status bar code in `ViewWillApear`.

I got this type of result:

[image]

Where am I doing wrong and how do I solve this?

Comment: try with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046070/uiimagepickercontroller-in-ios-7-status-bar

Comment: i already Try this same result... :(

Answer (score 3):

Have a try with:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden { return YES; }
```

It will hide the status bar.

On iOS 7, if you want to use `setStatusBarHidden:`, you need to set the `View controller-based status bar appearance` as NO in info.plist.

I hopes it will give you some hint.

---

Edited:

I found the problem.

This is the log the first time you show the homeViewController at viewWillAppear:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]
<__NSArrayM 0x8a74560>(
<UIWindow: 0x8e33360; frame = (0 20; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e348b0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8e3c6e0>>,
<UIWindow: 0x8c1db40; frame = (0 0; 320 20); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8c1e170>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8c1da80>>
)
```

And this is the log after dismissing the imagePicker and call the viewWillAppear:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]
<__NSArrayM 0x8c1a700>(
<UIWindow: 0x8e33360; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e348b0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8e3c6e0>>,
<UIWindow: 0x8c1db40; frame = (0 0; 320 20); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8c1e170>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8c1da80>>,
<UITextEffectsWindow: 0x8c53380; frame = (0 0; 320 568); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8c538a0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8c53520>>
)
```

The default window size changed. That is the reason the status bar can't be shown.

I edited your code like this, and it works for me:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    if(OVER_IOS7){
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width,screenHeight-20);
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

        UIWindow *defaultWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];

        defaultWindow.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,320,548);
        defaultWindow.bounds = CGRectMake(0,20,320,548);

        UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"userIsMale"]) {
            [tempWindow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(46.0/255.0) green:(134.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1]];
        }
        else {
            [tempWindow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(246.0/255.0) green:(26.0/255.0) blue:(113.0/255.0) alpha:1]];
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    }
}

- (IBAction)showImagePicker:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }];
}
```

Comment: one's i hiddne that ok after dismiss uiimagepicker then when i return show then it statusbar going to change

Comment: thx for effort but with your code replace then while Home view appar there status Bar appear over navigation bar like we faced this issue normally in ios7 statusBar issue

Comment: @NitinGohel Sorry, I don't quite understanding your meaning.In my understanding, you are making the status bar appears in home view, and disappears in image picker view.So that's my code's goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to present `UIImagePickerController` by:

```
UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
[tempWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:myImgPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I don't know if it will help you, but you maybe try it... :)

Another option is when you present `UIImagePickerController`. At that time set your view's frame as it was like at first and also hide status bar...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but there is only 1 way to overcome it.

Go to the info.plist file and set the value for "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "NO".

Comment: along with that you also need to add the following code in appdelegate---                                    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

Comment: Then add the mentioned code to the viewcontroller of business i.e the vc where you want the satus bar hidden

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue, but when I come back from the camera roll to my UIViewController. I solved the problem with the follow code in the controller that pushs the UIImagePickerController:

First I open the Picker

```
- (void)showPhotoPicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    [self.picker setSourceType:sourceType];
    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I keep the status bar without any problem, I saw some people have issues with that, I didn't

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
}
```

It is really important to call view needs layout on completition

```
// Apply photo selected
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.enterPicture setImage:info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){[self.view setNeedsLayout];}];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){[self.view  setNeedsLayout];}];
}
```

And here is the magic:

```
// fix the status bar & navigation bar after close the photo album on IOS7
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    UINavigationBar *navBar= [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7 && navBar) {
        CGFloat statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden] ? 0.0f : 20.0f;
        [navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, statusBarHeight, navBar.frame.size.width, navBar.frame.size.height)];
        [self.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, (statusBarHeight + navBar.frame.size.height) * -1, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```