# Status bar on iPad with iOS 7 (iPad/iPad mini)

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, statusbar

I have an application where I present an `UIImagePickerController` and I need to hide the status bar. The method I use to hide it works on iOS devices with 6.X OS and on iPhone/iPod Touch with 7.0, but the status bar is still visible on iPad/iPad mini devices with 7.0 OS.

Can someone tell me the reason why is not working on iOS 7.0 iPad devices?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760710/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: what method are you using?

Comment: Ilario please see my comments bellow.

Comment: Is your app iPhone only or universal? If it's iphone only the status bar might not disappear due to compatibility mode, in which case the only solution is to shift the elements on screen to make them visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your Plist file:

`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` and set it to `NO`

and

`UIStatusBarHidden` and set that one to `YES`

Comment: I set the Plist field to NO with no result. When I also added         `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];` it worked fine. I don't understand why I had to add this line also.

Comment: Did this really work for you? I have a same/similar problem in all of my iPhone targetted apps when running them on iPad mini only. No problem with iPad 4th gen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452638/status-bar-visible-on-ipad-mini-despite-setting-uiviewcontrollerbasedstatusbarap

Answer (score 1):

add this method to your viewcontroller
Note:Use this when you want dynamically to hide status bar

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried this also in combination with `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]` and the bar still appears.