# How can I hide the status bar in iOS 7.1. with iPhone app running in iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have used to the below methods to hide the status bar.

Set .plist configuration for hiding status bar and added below method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden 
{
    return YES;
}
```

But in iOS 7.1 update, the status bar not hides while running the app.
Does any one have a solution for this ?

**Issue exist with iPhone app while running on iPad**

Comment: This has been asked hundreds of times please do some research before asking. Voted to close.

Comment: @Popeye : I have seen this kind of questions many times.But couldn't found any solution for this.
The below link is the same what I am experiencing.
Kindly have a look into this and suggest a solution for this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452638/status-bar-visible-on-ipad-mini-despite-setting-uiviewcontrollerbasedstatusbarap

Comment: Well if that's the same as what you are experiencing then it is also a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Am seeking solutions, not just the questions.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your Info.plist:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..But it didn't worked for me in iOS 7.1

Comment: @ManuAntony Please add the updated answer code in each in each view

Answer (score -2):

Add this method in your code

```
-(void)hideStatusBar
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
    {
        [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    }
}


- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
   return YES;
}
```

In your viewDidLoad call this method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self hideStatusBar];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..But it didn't worked for me in iOS 7.1