# After imageview picker disable view are not set fixed frame

Tags: iphone, ios7

## How to solve this problem?

[image]

## click Add button open image video add

[image]

## After disble imagepickerview show this view

[image]

## How can i solve this problem?

Comment: status bar problem fix 20px from top

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760710/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-uiimagepickercontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This code :**

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
  {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
        self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);

        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    }

    return YES;

}
```