# status bar still visible after uipopovercontroller dismissed

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8.1

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)PhotoImportAction:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    else
    {
      popover=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:picker];
              popover.delegate=self;

        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:PhotoImportButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    }


}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *selectedImage=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    VisualEffectImageVIew.image=selectedImage;
    BackgroundImageView.image=selectedImage;
    ForegroundImageView.image=selectedImage;
   if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {

        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

  }
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Above code is pretty straightforward, everything works fine ,except `viewWillAppear` method that doesn't work on iPad after dismissal of `UIPopoverController` , so we tried using `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` method but the statusBar is still visible. Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760710/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: hiding status bar in UIImagePickerController breaks the swipeBack Navigation http://stackoverflow.com/q/29864197/4813721

Comment: are you sure your `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` method gets called?

Comment: Hmm I think you're right it's not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

From your code what I see is you have not set UIPopoverController's `delegate`.
add following line

```
 popover.delegate = self
```

before presenting the popover. Hope this works.

Comment: connected with delegate but still the method's not called.

Comment: Make sure your `ViewController` conforms `<UIPopoverControllerDelegate>` protocol.

Comment: the protocol is included otherwise I would get errors.

Comment: I saw your edited code you assign `popoverCon.delegate=self;` there is no `popoverCon` in the picture. I think it should be `popover.delegate=self`. Correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: in your popoverviewcontroller do you call `dismissPopoverAnimated:` method? if that is the case `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` won't be called. Here is the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPopoverControllerDelegate/popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:)

Comment: Yes in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method()

Comment: Coming back to your problem. You should find some other better place to hide the `statusBar` or call the `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` method yourself. :)

Comment: Yes, the delegate method will not be automatically called. So what you can do is call the method on your own after dismissing the popover in the popovercontroller.

Answer (score 1):

According to apple's documentation the method popoverControllerDidDismissPopover will not be called if popoverController is dismissed programatically.You can manually call the popoverControllerDidDismissPopover method.

```
[self popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:popoverController];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in viewdidload

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                            withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

and add new method

```
 - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
          return YES;
  }
```

also change info.plist file View controller-based status bar appearance" = NO

Comment: didn't work and yes we have set status bar is initially hidden to YES and view controller based status bar to NO.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the delegates of the popover. Please set it and check if delegate method is working or not...

Hope it helps :)

Comment: See my code carefully bro I have used it ,but it works only for uiimage picker controller and does not work for uipopovercontroller.