# Swift - Status Bar (Battery) show on camera

Tags: swift, camera, statusbar

I have a popover and inside that popover is a camera button, I have got the camera working perfectly but at the top the battery symbol overlaps the camera, heres a screenshot below.

If anyone knows the answer, it would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: A simple google search would have revealed a lot of answers to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760710/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: Yes, I did lots of looking on google and when through all of those. but nothing works. If i add the camera to a button on a normal VC it works fine, but when the button is inside a popover it doesnt seem to work correctly and I get that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **hide** the status bar for that view so it won't overlap the camera button and look kind of ugly. You can use this code:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Believe it or not, I just ran my app after the 20th time and its working properly! must of been some glitch! I'm sure your answer would of been right though! ;)